# How to access iPhone/ipad native camera app from IOS app?

Tags: ios, iphone, camera

In my application i want to create an exact replica of iOS 7.0 camera inside my app .Like android apps is it possible to call the native camera app in IOS 7.0/8.0.

Second question:

Using `UIImagePickerController` is it possible to  apply filters to photo ,slow mo ,pano?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access Default camera app using `UIImagePickerController`

Refer this link [ios-programming-camera-iphone](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-camera-iphone-app/)

Comment: Thanks NANNAV.apply filters, slow mo also possible in UIImagePickerController?

Comment: filters avilable in iOS8, else use custom UIImagePickerController in app